# Remove html special Char from displayed text

Tags: c#, string, html-entities

I have Xml witch a convert to plain text and then display with html formatting in a web browser.

At the end of each line the symbol ¶ appears i would like to remove the symbol or replace it with a .

Does anyone know how i could do this?

This is how i convert XML to plain text:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                        doc.LoadXml(this.dataGridViewResult.SelectedRows[0].Cells["XMLEvent"].Value.ToString());

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
  sb.Append(char.ToUpper(node.Name[0]));
  sb.Append(node.Name.Substring(1));
  sb.Append(' ');
  sb.AppendLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: ¶ = %B6 , In case people need to know this.

Comment: @Damith Like that it does not remove the chars must i put something in the breakets ??

Comment: `var finalText = sb.ToString().Replace("¶",".");`

Comment: you have several Appends, not sure where this special character adding, but you can finally remove it from the `sb` like above

Comment: @Damith Sadly nothing happend

Comment: How do spaces look? If they show as a small dot, then that is a sign that the application that displays your text "shows all characters" and added that ¶ as an end-of-line marker. It's not a real part of the text then.

Answer (score 2):

Where does the '¶' appear? Is it when you open the converted text file in an editor?

Normally that sign is used to visualize the end of line in a text editor, and it's not really part of you text. In many cases you have an option in the text editor to show/hide line ending markers.

However, if the output you are interested in is HTML, the character should not appear here.

Comment: It does not appear before i convert from XML to text so it appears somewhere in the conversion i have posed in my question.

Comment: it does not appear when i show result in a rich textbox but then my html formatting is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sb.AppendLine(node.InnerText.TrimEnd('¶'));
```

or

```
sb.AppendLine(node.InnerText.Replace("¶","."));
```

Comment: @ivowiblo No sorry they did not work, the did cause some changes to my display so i don't think your far off.

Comment: Is there no way to delete it from my string.

Comment: Which is the encoding of the text in the xml and the encoding of your page?

Answer (score 0):

After the `foreach` loop, Try:

```
sb.Replace("¶", ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in your case (assuming it's always at the end of the line), I'd use:

```
sb.AppendLine(node.InnerText.Replace('\u00b6', '.'));
```

If you want to keep your code unicode free.